# install debian lenny without gnome

Tags: linux, debian, debian-lenny

I want to install Debian Lenny, without any graphical desktop manager (like gnome).

I can install Debian Lenny with gnome and remove gnome from it, but i am not sure if it will remove all packages related to gnome.

There is one netinst CD image of Debian Lenny, my question is that, does it contain gnome or other graphical desktop manager? if it does not contain any graphical desktop manager, then i can use this CD image.

any other solution will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what image you use, at some point of the installation (if you provide a large enough image or an internet connection) you'll be prompted for a software selection, just uncheck `Desktop environment`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

netinst would install just what you tell it to - i often simply just let it install the base install and add what i need with tasksel - which is what cYrus is talking about.